# Integration Tests with PowerMock and Spring Boot

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot, mockito, powermock

I'm doing some integration tests, on a Spring Boot application.

Usually the integration tests that I was used to develop, was regarding the application domain, without any external service involved. 
Since this time I need to make an integration test on a service which uses both a database and an external service called by an SDK, I've tried doing something like the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(McpProductService::class)
class MyServiceIntegration {

    @Mock
    private ExternalService externalService;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MyServiceImpl myService;

    @Test
    public void thisTestShouldWork() {
        ...
    }
}
```

What is confusing me is: how should I declare `myService` attribute? Usually when I use Mockito + PowerMock in my Unit Tests, I usually test the implementation, not the whole Service Interface + Spring Injection. But I can't use `@Autowired` if I'm using just it's implementation, not the Interface.

Is there any best practice for this issue that I'm facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm assuming that what you are after is an end-to-end test of a service interface, backed by multiple classes. I assume (and hope) that you don't have a single class handling both database and webservice integration.

I don't see the need to use PowerMock here, it is usually something one would use for testing legacy code with a lot of static stuff. If you are using Spring boot, your code should be of a quality that makes PowerMock unnecessary.

When writing an end-to-end test, the principles are the same as a per-class unit test, only with a larger scope:

- With a unit test, you create an instance of the class under test, and mock all its external dependencies (other classes)
- With an end-to-end test, you create an "instance" of your module under test, and mock its external dependencies.

So, here you should find a mechanism to mock the parts of your code that communicates with external sources, like web service clients, database classes (if you don't use an in-memory db for your test (you should)). This will typically be a Spring config that is almost identical to the one used in production, but with said parts mocked out. Then, you just `@Inject` the parts you need to communicate with in order to complete the test.

Assuming that you use component scan and annotations for all beans, you could mock the endpoint-classes and use profiles:

This code is based on memory only, might not work on copy-paste, but hopefully you could use the concepts..

```
@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SomeWebserviceClient someWebserviceClient() {
        return mock(SomeWebserviceClient.class);
    }
}
```

Production code:

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject 
    private SomeWebserviceClient client;
}
```

Then in the test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SomeTest {
    @Inject
    private SomeClass someClass;

    @Inject
    private SomeWebserviceClient client; //<< will inject mock
}
```

Mock will also be injected into `SomeClass`

Comment: Well, everything you are saying is true. I'm in the middle between unit and e2e testing. What I'm trying to achieve is what you explain in the final part of your answer: Running tests that are using services that I implemented (using Spring context) but mocking `@Service`s that are going to external sources. What do you mean with "I assume (and hope) that you don't have a single class handling both database and webservice integration."? I've got a `@Service` with some `@Autowired` Services that can be internal or external.

Comment: I think we are on the same page then. The actual mechanism for doing this depends a bit on your project. I've done this with a regular spring project (not spring boot), then I had basically 3 config files, one for test (with mocks), one for production (with actual endpoints), and one commons used in both cases. With Spring boot I'm guessing you could use profiles. I'll update my answer, but can't guarantee that it will work 100%, since I don't have any real code examples at the time.

Comment: I'll try to get what I can from your answer then and try to figure out a solution, thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: What confuses me, is: why do you say that Powermock is bad? I mean, I find it very useful when unit testing. And I don't need to create different configuration for different environment, but only different properties for different environment. Also I can run different mock behaviour without creating methods and classes with Mockito...

Comment: PowerMock is bad because it manipulates byte code. It's good when you need to manipulate byte code (testing statics, private, etc), but that should not be necessary if you avoid static stuff (which you should with Spring). Properties won't help, if your code connects to an url for instance, it will fail unless it's a proper url.. You need to mock the whole class doing the connecting..